# UDP repeating through WIFI network extender

Tags: wireless-networking, udp, wireless-extender

I am using Rasplex as a media center down one end of my house which doesn't get WIFI. It's connected via ethernet, but then I have turned on it's 'wifi tether' feature, to extend the wifi to my phones/laptops also. It works well, however UDP broadcasts on the main network do not get through to devices connected to the Rasplex Wifi.

Is there a simple way to enable this, and if not, should I just be using an off-the-shelf wifi repeater to achieve what I want?

If the answer is the latter, is there something specific I need to look for in a repeater, to ensure that the UDP packets make it through to the extended devices? (Note: A wifi extender that uplinks to ethernet, and extends to Wifi is the only acceptable option to me, a wifi-wifi extender will not work due to my house's layout).

Thanks!

Comment: In lieu of a better answer, I have worked around the core hurdle simply by running mdns-repeater on the Rasplex device. https://bitbucket.org/geekman/mdns-repeater/